# How does the same origin policy apply to two different windows of a browser?

Tags: web-browser, chrome, same-origin-policy

One particular scenario I am interested in: If I a open one chrome browser window with `--disable-web-security` option, then SOP is disabled. Will this window be able to access data on websites opened in other window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--disable-web-security` option applies to the entire Chrome application, not to a particular window.

If you enable this option when starting Chrome, then any site you visit can access data from sites you visited earlier.

For example if I was looking at my Online Banking account, and then closed that tab and navigated to a malicious site, that malicious site would then have the ability to access my Online Banking account, transfer funds, etc. Note that this risk survives even after the tab is closed, and continues so long as you are still 'signed in' to the Online Banking account.

Also, it can survive restarts. So if

1. I sign into Gmail.
2. I restart the browser, now enabling `--disable-web-security`
3. I visit a malicious site.

Chances are, you are still signed into Gmail, because it often will not sign you out as an Online Banking site would. In that case the malicious site can access your Google account and control all services, as long as you have not yet Signed Out.

> Will this window be able to access data on websites opened in other window??

1. `--disable-web-security` applies to the whole browser, not just one window.
2. The 'other window' need not be open to for 'this window' to access data from that site.

So if you must use `--disable-web-security`, you should first Clear Private Data, especially Cookies & Saved Passwords. Then get your testing done, and then use the proper Exit feature at your earliest opportunity to get back into a safe browsing environment. Make sure your browser is fully Exited (not even a tray icon) before you assume you are back into a safe browsing session.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I was particularly interested in a case when one  browser window is opened normally and another browser window is opened **later** with the --disable-web-security option . How does this affect SOP in previous browser window ?

Comment: This was addressed in the first paragraph of my answer. *"The --disable-web-security option applies to the entire Chrome application, not to a particular window."*.

Comment: To clarify, if any window of Chrome is open, or it is running in the background (i.e. you can see it in the tray), then any new windows (even if you open them **later**) will inherit the **same** setting, regardless of the command line options you used **later**. So you have to **restart** Chrome completely if you want to enable or disable the `--disable-web-security` setting.

Comment: this was very helpful. kudos to you.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question: no, but read on.

The question is slightly unclear in that it asks about "data on websites opened".

If by data, you mean "*can a tab see the contents of another tab*", then no. The attack would come from JavaScript, a language whose security model is reference-based. Even if the rules on existing mechanisms are ignored because of a flag, there's still no way to "rip info" directly from other tabs/windows, because there's no web-content-facing "command" to get a list of all tabs, or even a handle to a specific tab.

If on the other hand, you meant "*can a tab re-fetch data from a server that the server has associated with another tab?*", then the answer is *possibly*. That's not easy to do however because most service providers don't require the SOP assumption as part of their security model, which would be foolhardy since python, curl, php etc all ignore the policy. **What is possible?**

1. guessing and checking for visited known site's tokens and cookies, like gmail/ SO/etc, using a hidden frame - "sniffing"
2. session hijacking in a targeted attack - "owning" (see George Bailey's answer)
3. tracking the $#%* out of you by looking at cookies/localStorage/perms - "spying"

---

none of the above are good, but with the non-exact term of "data on websites" i don't know if all apply...

Answer (score 0):

The origin constraint is between the active script (script in that specific browser tab) and the script that gets called.

It doesn't matter how you open other tabs, they are not part of the exchange and have no impact on it, except for possible opened sessions.  Active sessions will not affect the same origin constraint either.